# Trouble Replacing Apostrophe with Preg_Replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am attempting to remove apostrophes from text and it isn't really working.  It's got to be something small.

```
$text = preg_replace('/\'/', '', $text);
```

That's what I am using right now to remove it.  What am I doing wrong?

There is a series of these to remove special characters to turn them into urls and store them in my database.  However, a recent batch appeared with a &#39; where the ' was.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why are you using `preg_replace` instead of [`str_replace`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) or [`strtr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php)?

Comment: Works fine for me: http://www.ideone.com/ycu2E

Comment: It works for me (though everyone is right that preg_replace isn't appropriate). Maybe there's something wrong with your input.

Comment: I know this is old, but re-reading the question, it occurs to me that the code **was working**. The **real problem** was that the **input** was **not** an apostrophe. Somehow the HTML Entity (ampersand etc.) found it's way into the input. This can easily occur if the data was cut-n-pasted from a Word document or another web-site. So the **real solution** is any one of the answers below that suggested matching for **both** apostrophe **and** the HTML entity that represents apostrophe.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Have a go using [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php), it's quicker than [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) since it doesn't use regular expressions.

```
$text = str_replace("'", '', $text);
```

Answer (score 13):

you can use this regexp to remove apostrophes

```
$text = preg_replace('/(\'|&#0*39;)/', '', $text);
```

also you can use str_replace to remove apostrophes after doing html_entity_decode

```
$text = str_replace("'","", html_entity_decode($text, ENT_QUOTES));
```

Comment: [HTML Entity Boundaries – Zero Padding](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2010/02/25/html-entity-boundaries-zero-padding/).

Comment: $text = preg_replace('/(\'|&#0*39;)/', '', $text);

The only on solution that Work !

Answer (score 4):

&#039 represents the HTML entity encoding of an apostrophe, i.e. `htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES)`. You can check for both cases:

```
$text = "hey this is ' a couple of ' apostrophes with an encoding &#039;";
$text = preg_replace('/&#0*39;|\'/', '', $text);

// outputs: hey this is  a bunch of  apostraphes
echo $text;
```

You can also stick with the `str_replace()` equivalent (tends to run faster):

```
$text = "hey this is ' a couple of ' apostrophes with an encoding &#039;";
$text = str_replace(array("'", "&#039;"), '', $text);

// outputs: hey this is  a bunch of  apostraphes
echo $text;
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other answers, you may want to check for the **unicode** representation too?

```
$result = preg_replace('/([\'\x{0027}]|&#39;)/u', '', $subject);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using [string_replace](http://php.net/string_replace) for that, this doesn't require a regular expression.

```
$sText = preg_match("'", "", $sText);
```

That being said, the following snippet works as supposed in 5.3:

```
$text = "woo't";
$text = preg_replace('/\'/', '', $text);
echo $text; // woot
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem and it was stemming from the fact that text was being pasted from MS word which has it's own strange formatting

Solution was to first replace it and other weird characters with something which can be then captured by preg_replace or str_replace, the func below will help with that:

```
function msword_conversion($str)
{
    $str = str_replace(chr(130), ',', $str);    // baseline single quote
    $str = str_replace(chr(131), 'NLG', $str);  // florin
    $str = str_replace(chr(132), '"', $str);    // baseline double quote
    $str = str_replace(chr(133), '...', $str);  // ellipsis
    $str = str_replace(chr(134), '**', $str);   // dagger (a second footnote)
    $str = str_replace(chr(135), '***', $str);  // double dagger (a third footnote)
    $str = str_replace(chr(136), '^', $str);    // circumflex accent
    $str = str_replace(chr(137), 'o/oo', $str); // permile
    $str = str_replace(chr(138), 'Sh', $str);   // S Hacek
    $str = str_replace(chr(139), '<', $str);    // left single guillemet
// $str = str_replace(chr(140), 'OE', $str);   // OE ligature
    $str = str_replace(chr(145), "'", $str);    // left single quote
    $str = str_replace(chr(146), "'", $str);    // right single quote
// $str = str_replace(chr(147), '"', $str);    // left double quote
// $str = str_replace(chr(148), '"', $str);    // right double quote
    $str = str_replace(chr(149), '-', $str);    // bullet
    $str = str_replace(chr(150), '-–', $str);    // endash
    $str = str_replace(chr(151), '--', $str);   // emdash
// $str = str_replace(chr(152), '~', $str);    // tilde accent
// $str = str_replace(chr(153), '(TM)', $str); // trademark ligature
    $str = str_replace(chr(154), 'sh', $str);   // s Hacek
    $str = str_replace(chr(155), '>', $str);    // right single guillemet
// $str = str_replace(chr(156), 'oe', $str);   // oe ligature
    $str = str_replace(chr(159), 'Y', $str);    // Y Dieresis
    $str = str_replace('°C', '&deg;C', $str);    // Celcius is used quite a lot so it makes sense to add this in
    $str = str_replace('£', '&pound;', $str);
    $str = str_replace("'", "'", $str);
    $str = str_replace('"', '"', $str);
    $str = str_replace('–', '&ndash;', $str);

    return $str;
}
```

Source: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php